# Can USART protocol device connect with UART protocol devices?

Tags: stm32, uart, serial-communication, usart

I am trying to use STM32 which uses USART protocol to communicate with a UART protocol device. For the USART, I only use the tx and rx pin which mean it is working in  asynchronous mode. I am new to STM32 and a bit confuse about the USART and UART communication.

Comment: Very first sentence on wikipedia: A Universal Synchronous/Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter (USART) is a type of a serial interface device that can be programmed to communicate asynchronously or synchronously. See Universal asynchronous receiver/transmitter (UART) for a discussion of the asynchronous capabilities of these devices.

Comment: But if I set the USART to work in asynchronous mode, it works exactly like UART right? What if I set the USART to work in synchronous mode, can it still communicate with UART protocol devices?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself? best way to learn.

Comment: Cannot because USART got one more clock pin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are compatible in asynchronous mode. The USART can do synchronous communication, which the UART cannot, but both can do asynchronous. They are compatible at the register level, the UART registers just don't have the synchronous setting bit implemented. You can set up the USART exactly the same way as a UART to get asynchronous communication.